# Notebook with Multiple Frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter widow with multiple frames, but also the functions of notebook, like multiple widows. The problem is I am kind of unfamiliar with tkinter and am not sure how to do that. This is my current code, and it doesn't work, and would love to know what I should do to make it work. Again, the dream end result would be that I would have a first widow, which says the test text, and then the 2nd window which has multiple tabs.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


Font= ("Verdana", 8)
LargeFont = ("Verdana", 12)


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Info", font=LargeFont)
        label.pack(pady=2,padx=10)
        text = tk.Label(self, text="testtestestetetqwegfegeg\ntestwegwegwegweg", font=Font)
        text.pack(pady=2,padx=2)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the Card",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack(fill="x")


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        nb = ttk.Notebook(ttk.Frame())
        nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan = 50, rowspan=49, sticky='nesw')
        p1 = (nb)
        nb.add(p1, text='test')
        label = tk.Label(self, text="", font=LargeFont)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()





app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

The error that I eventually get is that it creates a third frame that is displayed with the test tab. Everything else works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you doing `nb = ttk.Notebook(ttk.Frame())`? That creates a new `ttk.Frame`, which you don't parent, just to make it the parent of your `ttk.Notebook`. I don't understand exactly what your problem is, but it sounds like it could be related to this.

Comment: @abarnert I am completely in the dark as to what I should do here, and am looking for what you would do in this case because I can't find any guides on this and don't know what I'm doing wrong either

Comment: IDLE now uses a ttk Notebook for the tabbed settings dialog.  Look at the idlelib.configdialog.ConfigDialog code for how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you mean because I'm trying the same. To me

```
    nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
```

worked.

best
Pkanda
Taubate Brazil